# org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 2

Tags: spring-boot, apache-spark, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using cassandra 3.11.11. It was running well, but now it' show this error when I run a query below. Important to say that nothing change in the app.

```
select * from table1 where date >= '2022-06-03 12:00:00' and date <= '2022-06-03 04:00:00';
```

> org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException:
> Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 2   at
> org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.CassandraQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.execute(CassandraQueryExecution.java:172)
> ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]  at
> org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.CassandraQueryExecution$ResultProcessingExecution.execute(CassandraQueryExecution.java:262)
> ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]  at
> org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.AbstractCassandraQuery.execute(AbstractCassandraQuery.java:105)
> ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]  at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]    at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]     at
> org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]    at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]     at
> org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]     at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]     at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]     at
> com.sun.proxy.$Proxy218.findById(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]     at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> ~[na:1.8.0_275]   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:1.8.0_275]   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:1.8.0_275]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> ~[na:1.8.0_275]   at
> org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]     at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]     at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]     at
> org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]  at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]     at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]     at
> com.sun.proxy.$Proxy218.findById(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]     at
> br.com.genesis.service.cadastro.SensorService.findById(SensorService.java:30)
> ~[classes/:2.4.2]     at
> br.com.genesis.controller.operacao.OpeGraficosOperacionaisController.carregaCombosRetorno(OpeGraficosOperacionaisController.java:2227)
> ~[classes/:2.4.2]     at
> br.com.genesis.controller.operacao.OpeGraficosOperacionaisController.gerarStatusComponentes(OpeGraficosOperacionaisController.java:281)
> ~[classes/:2.4.2]     at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> ~[na:1.8.0_275]   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:1.8.0_275]   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:1.8.0_275]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> ~[na:1.8.0_275]   at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]     at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]  at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
> ~[servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]  at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
> ~[servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
> [catalina.jar:9.0.41]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> [catalina.jar:9.0.41]     at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.41]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> [catalina.jar:9.0.41]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> [catalina.jar:9.0.41]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> [spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> [catalina.jar:9.0.41]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> [catalina.jar:9.0.41]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> [spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> [catalina.jar:9.0.41]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> [catalina.jar:9.0.41]     at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126)
> [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]     at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64)
> [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]     at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
> [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> [spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]  at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
> [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> [catalina.jar:9.0.41]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> [catalina.jar:9.0.41]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> [spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]  at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> [spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> [catalina.jar:9.0.41]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> [catalina.jar:9.0.41]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> [catalina.jar:9.0.41]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> [catalina.jar:9.0.41]     at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
> [catalina.jar:9.0.41]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
> [catalina.jar:9.0.41]     at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> [catalina.jar:9.0.41]     at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
> [catalina.jar:9.0.41]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> [catalina.jar:9.0.41]     at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> [catalina.jar:9.0.41]     at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
> [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.41]    at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.41]    at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
> [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.41]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
> [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.41]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.41]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> [na:1.8.0_275]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> [na:1.8.0_275]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.41]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> [na:1.8.0_275]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  have two rows of responses in output  whereas application (spring) is expecting only one. So please check your data in Cassandra and correct it there.